# Styling Wordpress error page

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to style the error page related to the error "This has been disabled".

This error comes up when people try to access the page https://benefacto.org/wp-admin/.

I thought maybe because it was a link with "wp-admin" it might be related to back-end styling?

I tried styling it with my stylesheet that is enqueued on the back-end it did not work.

Is there maybe a specific stylesheet I need to enqueue to style the error?

This is the styling I am trying to apply to the page:

```
/* Customises the WP-Error message on the login page */
body#error-page {
    background: #9100c0 !important;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the page I want to style:

[image]

The link for this page is "example.com/wp-admin"

I appreciate any help or suggestions! ^_^

Comment: can you provide me url if possible ? Or provide plugin name which you have used for admin url changes ?

Comment: URL would be helpful.

Comment: Here is the link "https://benefacto.org/wp-admin/"

Comment: ok checking wordpress core filter for update for this one

Comment: There have not any filter function. need to change in core. are you ready with it ?

Comment: http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1051/3812254390.png

Comment: Thanks Ravi for the help if you post the answer I will up vote it! Thanks for the help ^^

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43366#comment:1

Please check this one & override using changes of login_enqueue_scripts to wp_die_handler_css

Answer (score 1):

This one login page for update css. Error page for not any filter functions [more information](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43366#comment:1)

**Add this code on your activated theme's function.php**

```
function my_login_custom_css() { 
?>
    <style type="text/css">
            body#error-page{
                background-color:  #9100c0;
            }
    </style>
<?php }
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_custom_css' );
```